# Rでの特定データの順位付け

Tags: r

今，データフレームをとりこんで，例をあげるとこのようなかんじです。
このデータの「v2」に関して，aとbでグルーピングをし，それぞれのグループの中で順位をつけたいと思っています。

```
　　　   v1　　　　　v2　　　　　 v3　　　   v4
１　　H２９年　　　　a　         120  　　   m
２　　H２９年     　 a 　　　　　130 　　　   m
３　　H３０年  　　　a           105 　　　  m 
４　　H３０年        b          110      　 m
５　　H３０年        b  　　　　 125      　 f
```

そのために，以下の式をつくりました。※データフレームをxとおいています。

```
 x %>%
    +  dplyr::group_by("x$v2") %>%
    +  dplyr::mutate(good_ranks = order(order("x$v12", decreasing=TRUE)))
```

しかし，
 UseMethod("group_by_") でエラー:

```
'group_by_' をクラス "character" のオブジェクトに適用できるようなメソッドがありません
```

とエラーが出てきてしまいます。

どうすればよいでしょうか。
また，上記にあげた式に関わらず，グルーピングしたうえで，順位づけができるものがございましたら，ご教授ください。
ちなみに，tapplyをつかったところ，複数のグループに対してはうまく順位付けができませんでした。

初歩的なところで申し訳ございませんが，よろしくお願いします。

Comment: すいません，順位づけをおこないたいのは，V3のデータなので，
以下の式です。
x %>%
 + dplyr::group_by("x$v2") %>%
 + dplyr::mutate(good_ranks = order(order("x$v3", decreasing=TRUE)))

Comment: `x %>% dplyr::group_by(v2) %>% dplyr::mutate(good_ranks = order(order(v3, decreasing=TRUE)))` ではどうでしょうか。

Comment: >metropolisさん ご提案ありがとうございます。そのように打ちますと、groupbyをクラスfactorのオブジェクトにてきようできないとエラーが出てきてしまいます。

Comment: もしかするとデータフレームの作り方が異なるのかもしれません。こちらではデータフレーム `x` を `x <- data.frame("v1" = c("H２９年", ...), "v2" = c("a", ...), "v3" = c("120", ...), "v4" = c("m", ...))` の様に作成しています(コードが長いので適当に端折っています)。よろしければ、データフレームを作成している部分を質問文に追記していただけますか？

Comment: たびたびありがとうごさいます。データフレームは、csvファイルから取り込んでおります。列の名前もそのファイルから取り込んでおります。(x<-read.csv("～.csv",header=T))もしかして、元のデーダの作りが違いますと、応用も利かないのでしょうか。ご面倒お掛けしますが、よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: 「'group_by_' をクラス "character" のオブジェクトに適用できるようなメソッドがありません」というエラーメッセージが表示されるのは、`x` がデータフレームではなく character 型のオブジェクトではないかと思われます。`class(x)` を実行すると何が表示されますでしょうか？

Comment: 度々申し訳ありません。確認しましたところ、"data.frame"と表示されます。何かほかに必要な下準備などがあるのでしょうか。

Comment: 念の為に確認しますが、、、`x %>% + dplyr::group_by("x$v2") ...` となっている部分の `+` 記号を入力していませんか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。プラスをこちらで入力しておりました。大変助かりました。その点解消いたしましたが、Error in format.pillar_shaft_decimal(x$shaft, width = width, ...) : 
   Need at least width 6 requested 5.FALSEと出てくるようになってしまいました。